# HTML form PUT method by tunneling, something I don't understaand

Tags: php, apache

HTML can't be used to submit a PUT request via a form. You can only do it via javascript as an ajax request. Ok.  On another post someone said (with +40 on the answer):

> Browsers only support POST and GET, if you need PUT, you have to send the form via post/get and then do the proper PUT request on server-side.

Does this mean that you could upload a file using a form (lets say POST method), but the server interprets it as PUT method? But if the request is handled as a POST method, you couldn't stream data to the server the same way you could with PUT, so I don't understand. Please could someone clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use POST or GET in the browser. Some REST implementations use a 'method override' variable to indicate to the server that you actually want a different method
(see http://docs.slimframework.com/ search for 'Method Override')

This is just a simple hidden variable and you can apply your own conventions to it, then just react to it in your server side code.

EDIT: (clarification)
Browsers do not support anything other than POST/GET via standard HTML forms. You can set up a mechanism to let your application know that you meant to send via another method, but the web server will still handle it as a POST.

Comment: hi, sorry I still don't understand. What do you mean conventions, and what do you mean react to it? The apache server will wait for all POST data to be received before deciding what to do with it, whereas in a traditional PUT method apache will pass the data to the destination as bits are received.

Comment: Browsers do not support PUT, so you will not be able to stream in that way with a normal HTML form. You can only indicate to your server-side script that you want to 'pretend' it's a PUT to make your application more RESTful. The request will still be handled by the web server as a POST.